# CakePHP3 path to template file error on json calls

Tags: json, cakephp3

I've just converted an ajax call to return json instead of HTML.

If I

- make the request manually or via postman I get the expected result.
- call from my site using ajax I get an error.
- use devtools/Network to open in new tab I get the expected result.

Why is cake processing it differently?

Why is it adding the extra /json to the template path?

```
code: 500
file: "Forms/json/json/get_more.ctp"
line: 1092
message: "Template file "Forms/json/json/get_more.ctp" is missing."
url: "/forms/getMore/60498/0/6?_=1599996955252"
```

Adding .json to the URL makes no difference.

I've added to routes.php
`$routes->extensions(['json', 'xml', 'html']);`

I need to use a template in order to get my helper to process some data so I have `$this->set('_serialize', false);`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the code in routes.php

```
$routes->extensions(['json']);
```

inside the the function

```
Router::scope('/', function (RouteBuilder $routes) {
```

Now, in controller assuming $responseArray is the response you want in json you have to write the below lines at the end of the action.

```
$this->set('responseRoot', $responseArray);
$this->set('_serialize', array('responseRoot'));
```

Delete the ctp file, they are not required for .json type requests unless you want a specific type of formatting.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the method ajax of jquery, remove the param dataType

```
//  dataType: 'json',
```